# Internet Explorer CSS Flip Animation Issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations, flip

I've hit a dead-end figuring out how to make this flip animation work in IE. The HTML and CSS are below. The live demo is at http://designatwork.net/precision/. It works fine in Chrome and FF, but giving me hell in IE, specifically version 10/11. Any thoughts on a fix that will make it consistent across all browsers?

```
<div class="row hidden-xs">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 min-gutter">
        <div class="home-box-1">
         <p>Collections and billing are vital elements of any successful practice, but they're not the reason you got in to medicine. Refocus your efforts on patient care and <b>get back to what matters</b> with Precision Medical Billing (PMB).</p>
        </div>
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 min-gutter">
        <div class="row full-gutter">
          <div class="col-md-6 min-gutter">
            <div class="home-box-2"  ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
              <div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                  <div class="front">
                    <a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/services/physicians-services/"><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/hb2-front.jpg" width="95" height="110" alt=""></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="back">
                    <a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/services/physicians-services/"><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/hb2-back.jpg" width="95" height="110" alt=""></a>
                  </div>
                </div>         
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 min-gutter">
            <div class="home-box-3"  ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
              <div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                  <div class="front">
                    <a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/services/physicians-services/"><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/hb3-front.jpg" width="95" height="110" alt=""></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="back">
                    <a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/services/physicians-services/"><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/hb3-back4.jpg" width="95" height="110" alt=""></a>
                  </div>
                </div>         
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row full-gutter">
          <div class="col-md-12 min-gutter">
            <div class="home-box-4"  ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
              <div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                  <div class="front">
                    <a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/services/home-health-hospice-care-providers/"><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/hb4-front.jpg" width="200" height="95" alt=""></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="back">
                    <a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/services/home-health-hospice-care-providers/"><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/hb4-back.jpg" width="200" height="95" alt=""></a>
                  </div>
                </div>         
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 min-gutter">
        <div class="home-box-5"  ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="flip-container">
            <div class="flipper">
              <div class="front">
                <a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/training/"><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/hb5-front.png" width="200" height="215" alt=""></a>
              </div>
              <div class="back">
                <div class="home-box-5-back">
                  <p>Webinars and<br />on-demand videos</p>
                  <p><a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/training/"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><br />Physicians »</a></p>
                  <p><a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/training/"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><br />Home Health &amp; Hospice Care Providers »</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>         
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 min-gutter">
        <div class="home-box-6"  ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="flip-container">
            <div class="flipper">
              <div class="front">
                <a href=""><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/hb6-front.png" width="129" height="215" alt=""></a>
              </div>
              <div class="back">
                <div class="home-box-6-back">
                  <p>Valuable tools<br />and information<br />to improve your<br />day-to-day</p>
                  <p><a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/resources/physicians-resources/"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Physicians »</a></p>
                  <p><a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/resources/home-health-hospice-resources/"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Home Health &amp; Hospice Care Providers »</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>         
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row middle-row">
      <div class="col-md-5 min-gutter">
        <div class="home-box-7">
            <p>Request your free<br />consultation</p>
            <a href="#consultation" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#consultation">Get Started</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 min-gutter">
        <div class="home-box-8">
          <img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/involved-active2.png" width="480" height="204" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row middle-row">
      <div class="col-md-7 min-gutter">
        <div class="home-box-9"  ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="flip-container">
            <div class="flipper">
              <div class="front">
                <a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/news-events/"><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/hb9-front.jpg" width="485" height="100" alt=""></a>
              </div>
              <div class="back">
                <a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/news-events/"><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/hb9-back.jpg" width="485" height="100" alt=""></a>
              </div>
            </div>         
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 min-gutter">
        <div class="home-box-10"  ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="flip-container">
            <div class="flipper">
              <div class="front">
                <a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/about-us/"><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/hb10-front.png" width="125" height="100" alt=""></a>
              </div>
              <div class="back">
                <a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/about-us/"><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/hb10-back.jpg" width="125" height="100" alt=""></a>
              </div>
            </div>         
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 min-gutter">
        <div class="home-box-11"  ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class="flip-container">
            <div class="flipper">
              <div class="front">
                <a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/contact/"><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/hb11-front.jpg" width="200" height="100" alt="contact"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="back">
                <a href="http://designatwork.net/precision/contact/"><img src="http://designatwork.net/precision/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/hb11-back2.jpg" width="200" height="100" alt="contact"></a>
              </div>
            </div>         
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>

/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -ms-perspective: 1000;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.flip-container:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-container:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transition: ease-in-out 1.0s;
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transition: ease-in-out 1.0s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out 1.0s;
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 100%;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 1.0s;
  -ms-transition: 1.0s;
  -webkit-transition: 1.0s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preverve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preverve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 1.0s;
  -webkit-transition: 1.0s;
  -ms-transition: 1.0s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition: ease-in-out 1.0s;
  -ms-transition: ease-in-out 1.0s;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out 1.0s;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transition: ease-in-out 1.0s;
  -ms-transition: ease-in-out 1.0s;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out 1.0s;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly well in IE10-11 on Windows 10. Don't see the issue. **Notes**: posting the CSS is more useful. Why do you use images, where you could have used HTML and CSS. In the test case (but not in the code you posted) you have empty `href`s, this is not done. When using browser specific properties in CSS, always put the non-prefixed version *last* as it could then overwrite browser-specific behaviour.

Comment: IE 10-11 on Windows 10 works fine, but on Windows 8, no good.